# How to hide Zend's application.ini from the public?

Tags: zend-framework

I am using the Zend Framework for construction of my site, which uses the application.ini file to store database info (such as username and password). I discovered that typing /application/configs/application.ini in the web browser plainly shows all the contents of the applications.ini file.
How can I prevent this? I tried setting the chmod public access to nothing, but then the website couldn't function anymore because of access rights. Anyone familiar with this?

Comment: application.ini (and the application directory as a whole) should never be within your web root. Your vhost should point at public - how is your app structured?

Comment: it is structured like the answer by Alex Howansky. How do I set the vhost?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your document root setting in your web server configuration should point to the subdirectory that has your index.php in it, not the top-level directory of the whole application install.

E.g., you have something like:

```
myapp/application/Bootstrap.php
myapp/application/configs/application.ini
myapp/application/controllers/...
myapp/application/views/...
myapp/library/...
myapp/tests/...
myapp/public/index.php
```

Set your document_root to myapp/public and ***not*** myapp.

Comment: Does that have any effect on how urls work in my code? e.g. includes, fopens, etc?

Comment: For internal references (like in fopen()) there should be no change. For external references (like a URL), you'll no longer use http://mydomain.com/myapp/public/index.php -- you'll use http://mydomain.com/index.php

Answer (score 4):

I solved this problem by writing the following in the `.htaccess` file:

```
<Files application.ini>
  order allow,deny
  deny from all
</Files>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have access to change your document root and you are using the Apache web server, the "quick and dirty" approach might be to create a ".htaccess" file with the following contents, created in:

```
/application/configs
```

Contents:

```
deny from all
```